# Enable addEventListener callback to do put's

Tags: redux-saga

I need to do a global `addEventListener` like thing. I am using react native and need to listen for deep link redirect events. I couldn't figure out the redux-saga way to do this. I need to enable a `put` from the callback within the addEventListener.

I currently do the bad hack of importing `store` then doing `store.dispatch(...)` as seen here:

```
import store from './flow-control'

Linking.addEventListener('url', ({ url }) => store.dispatch(_redir(url)));
```

Is there a redux-saga way to do this?

I was hoping to put this into a a saga maybe:

```
function* reduxSaga() {

    const url = yield Linking.addEventListener('url', ({ url }) => ???);

}
```

Or at the least replace store.dispatch with put like this:

```
import { put } from 'redux-saga/effects'

Linking.addEventListener('url', ({ url }) => put(_redir(url)));
```

Whats the right way to do this with redux-saga?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One possible solution, is to use channels. Here is an example that should work in your case:

```
import { channel } from 'redux-saga'
import { put, take, race } from 'redux-saga/effects'

const redirectChannel = channel()

export function* startRedirectChannel(id) {
  Linking.addEventListener('url', ({ url }) => redirectChannel.put({
    type: REDIRECT,
    url,
  }))
}

export function* watchRedirectChannel() {
  while (true) {
    const action = yield take(redirectChannel)
    yield put(action)
  }
}
```

The idea here is that we will push a REDIRECT action on the channel for each url event that is emitted from Linking.addEventListener.

We also have to start another saga function that is listening to each pushed action in a while loop (watchRedirectChannel). Everytime an action has been taken from the channel, we use the normal yield put to tell redux-saga that this action should be dispatched.

Here an example using the `eventChannel` API:

```
import { eventChannel } from 'redux-saga'
import { put, take } from 'redux-saga/effects'

export function* watchRedirect() {
  const redirectChannel = eventChannel(emitter => {
    Linking.addEventListener('url', emitter)

    // The subscriber must return an unsubscribe function
    return () => {
      Linking.removeEventListener('url', emitter)
    }
  })

  while (true) {
    const { redirectEvent, cancelEvent } = race({
      redirectEvent: take(redirectChannel),
      cancelEvent: take(ACTION_Y),
    })

    if (redirectEvent) {
      yield put({
        type: REDIRECT,
        url,
      })
    } else {
      redirectChannel.close()
      return
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Very interesting thanks Alex. Is it possible to use `eventChannel` for this? It says here https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/Channels.html for "external events". It sounds like its my case but im not sure. I'm new to channels. Thanks Alex!

Comment: It also seems creating a channel like this takes only first buffers just 10 messages - per here - https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/ - is it possible to have unlimited buffer here?

Comment: You can also use the `eventChannel` API. `eventChannel` let's you return an unsubscribe function as well an `END` event. The `buffer` should be of no concern here, as the watcher immediately takes all incoming `REDIRECT` action's

Comment: Thanks Alex! May you please show me an eventChannel example that spins up when it gets ACTION_X and unsubscribes/remvoes listener on ACTION_Y - im totally lost on the even channel

Comment: I updated the answer. For starting the saga with `ACTION_X` just use `takeLatest`

Comment: I have used the technique above. Here is an example that integrates this approach with the app's initialization/termination logic https://gist.github.com/yaraabdallah10/c10e4a2739874bdb50b40305f3add1d8